# Convergence of $\sum \frac{1}{\sqrt{4n + 1}} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{4n + 3}}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I need to prove $\sum \frac{1}{\sqrt{4n + 1}} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{4n + 3}}$ converges. The root test is inconclusive, so I check in W.A., $\sum \frac{1}{\sqrt{4n + 1}} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{4n + 3}}$ converges by comparison test, but I don't know what series to compare. I've tried to compare with $\sum \frac{1}{4n+1} - \frac{1}{4n + 3}$ because this serie converges to $\frac{\pi}{4}$, but we have exactly the opposite inaquality $\frac{1}{\sqrt{4n + 1}} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{4n + 3}} > \frac{1}{4n + 1} - \frac{1}{4n + 3}$.

Can you help me?

Comment: split each term into two and apply [alternating series test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test).

Answer (score 5):

**Hint** $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{4n + 1}} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{4n + 3}} = \frac{\sqrt{4n + 3}-\sqrt{4n + 1}}{\sqrt{4n + 3}\sqrt{4n + 1}}=\frac{2}{\sqrt{4n + 3}\sqrt{4n + 1}(\sqrt{4n + 3}+\sqrt{4n + 1})}.$$

Answer (score 2):

Another possible solution:
$$
0 < a_n := \frac{1}{\sqrt{4n + 1}} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{4n + 3}}
 = \frac{1}{\sqrt{4n + 1}} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{4(n+1) - 1}} \\
 < \frac{1}{\sqrt{4n + 1}} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{4(n+1) + 1}} =: b_n
$$
and $\sum b_n$ is convergent as a *telescoping series.*
It follows that $\sum a_n$ is convergent and
$$
 \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n < \sum_{n=0}^\infty b_n = 1 \quad .
$$

Or: The terms are positive, and the partial sums
$$
\sum_{n=0}^N \frac{1}{\sqrt{4n + 1}} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{4n + 3}} =
1 + \sum_{n=1}^N \left(-\frac{1}{\sqrt{4n - 1}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{4n + 1}} \right) - \frac{1}{\sqrt{4N + 3}} < 1
$$
are *bounded*. (This is essentially what [achille hui suggested
in the above comment.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1743725/convergence-of-sum-frac1-sqrt4n-1-frac1-sqrt4n-3/1743736#comment3558155_1743725))

Answer (score 0):

Asmptotics.
As $n \to +\infty$:
$$\begin{align}
(4n+1)^{-1/2} &= (4n)^{-1/2}\left(1+\frac{1}{4n}\right)^{-1/2}
=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}}\left(1-\frac{1}{8n}+O(n^{-2})\right)
\\
(4n+3)^{-1/2} &= (4n)^{-1/2}\left(1+\frac{3}{4n}\right)^{-1/2}
=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}}\left(1-\frac{3}{8n}+O(n^{-2})\right)
\\
(4n+1)^{-1/2} - (4n+3)^{-1/2}&=
\frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}}\left(0+\frac{2}{8n}+O(n^{-2})\right)
=\frac{1}{8n^{3/2}}+O(n^{-5/2})
\end{align}$$
The series converges by comparison with $$\sum\frac{1}{8n^{3/2}}$$